# Joining multiple columns (value not known until procedure start)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I am using SQL Server 2008, and I have a task to make some reports that will require me to sort some data then `JOIN` with a table. I am writing a procedure for this. It looks a bit like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getReport @ReportType int
AS
   DECLARE @DataToJoin table
  --DETAILS OMMITTED

  INSERT INTO @DataToJoin
  --DETAILS OMMITTED (sorting, fiddling with data)

  SELECT table.col1, table.col2, joined.col3
  FROM table
  JOIN @DataToJoin joined ON table.x=joined.x
GO
```

Everything seemed to be good till someone told me that `@ReportType` tells us about how many things to sort and then to join. Since this data needs to be fiddled with, it can't be a simple `JOIN` from the start.

How should I approach the matter of multiple `JOIN`s to return one table? Initially I thought about `WHILE` within the last select that will have sorting and joining within it, but it seems that taking this approach won't work :( Then I thought about another table that will hold joined columns, but I can't declare table that will have dynamic list of columns.

Any thoughts on that matter? Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: It's *columns* - not *collumns* (one "l" is quite good enough!)

Comment: true, thanks and sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building dynamic sql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx
This way you can create a sql with all the table JOIN together and sorted any way you needed.